# Python program uses too much memory

Tags: python, optimization

Function `coinT()` tests if two time series are stationary using ADF test and Hurst exponent. Time series are stored in 1511x6 CSV files, but for testing only a vector of the 5th column is returned by the function `stock()`. There are 50 files in total. It seems that the program is using too much memory as it makes the PC crash after running for ~30 secs. It works fine on 15 files, but crashes on larger sets(>50).

Can somebody please help me find out what's using so much memory? I've tried splitting computations into multiple functions and deleting the object, but it didn't help much.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as ts
import csv
import timeit
from numpy import log, polyfit, sqrt, std, subtract
from pandas.stats.api import ols
import os

src = 'C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Magistr/Ibpython/testing/'
filenames = next(os.walk(src))[2] #load all stock file names into array
cointegratedPairs = []

def hurst(ts):
"""Returns the Hurst Exponent of the time series vector ts
    H<0.5 - The time series is mean reverting
    H=0.5 - The time series is a Geometric Brownian Motion
    H>0.5 - The time series is trending"""

    # Create the range of lag values
    lags = range(2, 100)

    # Calculate the array of the variances of the lagged differences
    tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]

    # Use a linear fit to estimate the Hurst Exponent
    poly = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1)

    del lags
    del tau

    # Return the Hurst exponent from the polyfit output
    return poly[0]*2.0

#Convert file into an array
def stock(filename):
    #read file into array and get it's length
    delimiter = ","
    with open(src + filename,'r') as dest_f:
        data_iter = csv.reader(dest_f, 
                            delimiter = delimiter, 
                            quotechar = '"')
        data = [data for data in data_iter]
    data_array = np.asarray(data)[:,5]
    return data_array

   del data
   del data_array

#Check if two time series are cointegrated
def coinTest(itemX, itemY):
    indVar = map(float, stock(itemX)[0:1000]) #2009.05.22 - 2013.05.14
    depVar = map(float, stock(itemY)[0:1000]) #2009.05.22 - 2013.05.14

    #Calculate optimal hedge ratio "beta"
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df[itemX] = indVar
    df[itemY] = depVar

    res = ols(y=df[itemY], x=df[itemX])
    beta_hr = res.beta.x
    alpha = res.beta.intercept
    df["res"] = df[itemY] - beta_hr*df[itemX] - alpha

    #Calculate the CADF test on the residuals
    cadf = ts.adfuller(df["res"])

    #Reject the null hypothesis at 1% confidence level
    if cadf[4]['1%'] > cadf[0]:

    #Hurst exponent test if residuals are mean reverting
        if hurst(df["res"]) < 0.4:
            cointegratedPairs.append((itemY,itemX))
    del indVar
    del depVar  
    del df[itemX]
    del df[itemY]
    del df["res"]   
    del cadf  

#Main function
def coinT():
    limit = 0
    TotalPairs = 0

    for itemX in filenames:
        for itemY in filenames[limit:]:
            TotalPairs +=1
            if itemX == itemY:
                next
            else:
                coinTest(itemX, itemY) 

        limit +=1
```

Comment: That's not a memory leak, it's just high memory usage.

Comment: I have 8Gb of RAM, is it really that computationally intensive? Shouldn't it clear the memory after each time it runs a coinT() test on a pair, since it's done in a separate function? this was my initial idea

Comment: After a quick glance at the code, it is hard to say what should be optimized. You should run this with the [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) that will tell you line per line which part takes the most memory.

Comment: My guess is that it's a problem in adfuller autolag option that keeps all auxiliary regression models in memory (bad design). You need to set either a smaller maxlag or drop the autolag option.